# Get current category id of the product in search result

Tags: product, search, category-products, category-attribute

Is it possible to get the category id from which the product is loaded in search result?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but you have to keep in mind that one product can be assigned to several categories.

To retrieve the category Ids of a product you can use the following code:

```
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
```

Then if you want more details about the category you can loop through the array of IDs and retrieve data:

```
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
    echo $_cat->getName();
}
```

Comment: I just need the cat id from which the product is loaded when I choose to view the product displayed in search result. Btw will this work for PDP?

Comment: The problem is: search result does not load products from a category. It loads the products directly from the database based on your search criteria.

Comment: Thats what my problem is.. :(

Comment: Is there any way to get cat info in search page?????

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer, that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Let me try this and update you

Answer (score 0):

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(6);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();